# How to completely hide a table header in views?

Tags: 7, views, theming

In views when you use the table layout and don't select labels it still creates an empty header, for example:

```
<th class="views-field views-field-field-address-1"></th>
```

I can hide it with CSS. What would I have to do to access the render array and unset the element before the HTML is generated?

Is there any other way to remove the `<th>` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement `hook_preprocess_views_view_table(&$vars)` in theme or custom module and set `$vars['header']` to empty array. Template completely ignores thead when header variable is empty. For example:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_views_view_table(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == "my_view") {
    $vars['header'] = array();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! They are getting close fixing it in views: http://drupal.org/node/1309026#new

Answer (score 4):

A more general solution to the problem could be implemented in your theme by preprocessing the theme_table.

In other words, in your template.php file of your theme, write a function like this:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_table(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['header'])) {
    foreach($variables['header'] as $cell) {
      if (!empty($cell)) {
        return;
      }
    }
    $variables['header'] = array();
  }
}
```